# Restoring MySQL Database in Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: mysql, database, cloud9-ide, database-restore

I'm working on a Wordpress site and accidentally ended up modifying the Database via PHPMyAdmin in a way that affected all the posts on the website negatively. I regret the fact that I should have manually made a DB backup before working on it. After having tried to resolve it by importing the original data I had at first, I seem to have lost more data than I anticipated. Is it possible to restore the Cloud9 MySQL Database to a specific data and time in the past?

Comment: Probably more appropriate to http://serverfault.com or to your hosting provider.

Comment: You should contact support@c9.io and they may have a backup you can restore from.